# How to increment array by pointing to address using integer

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

I wrote a function that I expect to read measurements of a transmitter and store them into an array.

I am pointing to the array using an integer because a for loop would not be suitable in this case. However, it does not store the readings in the array.
Here is the code:

```
void readTemperature()
{
    readings[count] = tx.read();
    count++;
    lcd.printf("%.2f\n",readings[0]);        
}
```

e.g 27.60

Comment: What does `tx.read()` return?

Comment: You need to post a lot more code.

Comment: tx.read() returns a transmitter reading e.g 27.60, readings is an array initialized to store a max of 100 transmitter readings

Comment: How do you avoid to overflow the `readings` array? I would suggest to use `vector`.

Comment: What value does count have?  Does it ever have the value 0?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- `readings` is a pointer to float (or an array of float),
- `readings` was correctly initialized,
- `count` was intialized to 0,
- and that the problem is that the last output doesn't match the value read;

Then, you need to display the last value read, because in your code you always display the same first value:

```
void readTemperature()
{
    readings[count] = tx.read();
    lcd.printf("%.2f\n",readings[count]);   // not [0]
    count++;
}
```

In addition, you should check that count is smaller than the size of the allocated array, in order to avoid any risk of memory corruption.

***Note:*** The term "pointing to an array using an integer" is ambiguous and confusing.  You could go for the less ambiguous "access an array by indexing a pointer" or something like this.

Comment: It worked. Thanks  a lot.